# How to find which methods/functions of a Project is used in another Project is VS 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution which has two projects Project1 and Project2. Project1 refers to Project2. Project2 has a number of methods/functions that is used across different classes inside Project1. How can find out all the methods/functions of Project2 that are used in Project1?. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

I am using .NET framework 4.0 and C#

I have already read the thread the following thread, which is related to an assembly (possibily without source code) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606360/how-to-find-out-wich-methods-from-an-assembly-are-being-used-in-another-assembly

**Edit**

The answers suggest that I use tools like ReSharper and NDpend. These are not free tools, even though it might meet my need. I do not want to spend big money for such a small feature.

Comment: ReSharper is worth every penny of the cost, and is really not that much compared to other programming tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is a great tool for tasks like this. It e.g. provides a dependency matrix which you can expand/collapse:

[image: NDepend dependency matrix]

*Image from NDepend homepage*

Comment: I would be interested to know if you know any free tool.

Comment: No sorry. I'm using NDepend because I didn't find a similar free tool. If you use the other features as well, it's certainly worth the money. E.g. in one of my projects, I identified all references to legacy components, even by ProgID or GUID and was able to remove all of them.

Comment: I agree with you. I just downloaded evaluation version of NDepend and I got what I needed. The features in NDepend is simply Awesome!.

Answer (score 0):

There's a extremely simple solution for this: remove the reference of `Project2` on `Project1` and build `Project1`. You'll instantly get all classes that aren't present in `Project1` but in `Project2` as build errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove reference to Project2 from Project1. Then go through the error list and you'll get the methods.

EDIT: you can use Resharper, which can find all usages of project (and of a class, a method ...)

Comment: I can do this, but I thought I am missing some feature or some known way of doing this rather than removing the references, which I do not prefer.

Answer (score 0):

**Right-click** on **solution**, choose **Project Dependencies**, choose the first project in the Projects drop down list, and scroll over projects.

It's easier using Resharper:

**Right-click** on module and choose **Project Hierarchy**, then click **Referencing projects** to see all project references

Comment: My question was not about finding project references, but a list of methods/functions of referred project (Project2), in the referring Project (Project1)